# Android recyclerview not update holder when call notifyItemChanged, payload have not value

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem. When I update one view of the `ListView`, I notify one item. Data have 2 items.

But when I call `notifyItem` with payload, but payload return array none. I don't know why before I call success with a view different.

`RecyclerView` with call update one item at `updateStatusIconCheckLanguage`. I check normal update button no have value payload. Can help you? Thanks.

This is the code :

```
public class HistoryAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<HistoryModel> mDataLists;
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private IViewCallback mCallback;

    public HistoryAdapter() {
        mDataLists = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void fillData(List<HistoryModel> modelList) {
        if (modelList == null) {
            return;
        }

        //remember  order item.
        mDataLists = new ArrayList<>();
        mDataLists.addAll(modelList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        updateStatusIconCheckLanguage(KEY_TYPE_LANGUAGE.KEY_VN);
    }

    public void updateStatusIconCheckLanguage(KEY_TYPE_LANGUAGE keyTypeLanguage) {
        if (keyTypeLanguage != null) {
            if (mDataLists != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mDataLists.size(); i++) {
                    notifyItemChanged(i, 34444);
                    CommonUtils.showLogDebug("notifyItemChanged");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void cleanupResources() {
        if (mViewHolder != null) {
            mViewHolder.cleanupResources();
            mViewHolder = null;
        }
        mDataLists = null;

        // Refresh your adapter.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) {
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(mCallback, LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_history, parent, false));

        return mViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,
                                 int position) {
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("onBindViewHolder");
        HistoryModel model = mDataLists.get(position);
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
            ((ViewHolder) holder).fillData(model);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,
                                 final int position,
                                 @NonNull final List<Object> payloads) {
        CommonUtils.showLogDebug("ssss.size()" + payloads + holder);

        if (payloads.size() > 0) {

        } else {
            onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        }
    }

    public void setOnClickItemViewListener(IViewCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public interface IViewCallback {
        void onViewClicked(HistoryModel model);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // add them 1 vi co header.
        // return mNormalWithExoPlayerModelList.size();
        return mDataLists == null ? 0 : mDataLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.clItemHistory)
        ConstraintLayout clItemHistory;
        @BindView(R.id.tvItemHistory)
        TextView tvItemHistory;

        private Unbinder mUnbinder;
        private HistoryModel mModel;
        private IViewCallback mCallback;

        ViewHolder(IViewCallback callback,
                   View view) {
            super(view);
            mCallback = callback;
            mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        }

        @OnClick(R.id.clItemHistory)
        protected void onViewClicked() {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onViewClicked(mModel);
            }
        }

        void fillData(HistoryModel model) {
            if ((model != null)) {
                mModel = model;
                tvItemHistory.setText(String.format("%s-%s-%s",
                                                    model.getDayOfHistory(),
                                                    model.getMonthOfHistory(),
                                                    model.getYearOfHistory()));
            }
        }

        void cleanupResources() {
            mModel = null;
            if (clItemHistory != null) {
                clItemHistory.removeAllViews();
            }

            if (mUnbinder != null) {
                mUnbinder.unbind();
                mUnbinder = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see "notifyItemChanged" log?

Comment: I see, and log at  CommonUtils.showLogDebug("ssss.size()" + payloads + holder);
with payload []

Comment: Did you solve? I am in trouble with this problem,,

Comment: no :( but have change use submitList of RecyclerView.Adapter